# how do I select text in VSCode's diff view?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So recently(?) they have changed something and introduced this fancy new diff view, in which I am no longer able to precisely select the text that I want to (e.g.) copy because a context menu appears immediately after clicking on the view.

[image: a diff view with the context menu opened]

Any ideas how to workaround that?

Comment: F1 + "compare: toggle inline view"

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. I can select and copy and paste text just find. Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.